# git fails silently and curl https fails with illegal instruction

Tags: git, ssl, curl, centos, cpanel

Just recently my staging server has been unable to perform `git pull` or `git fetch`.

```
git pull origin master
```

Running that doesn't have any effect at all, no error message given, no files changed, it just returns to the prompt. It used to work (a couple of weeks ago), so I'm not sure what's changed in the meantime. The remote is definitely correct.

After a lot of searching I've narrowed it down to an underlying curl issue, but I'm struggling to find a solution.

```
curl https://www.google.co.uk -v
```

gives me:

```
* About to connect() to www.google.co.uk port 443 (#0)
* Trying 216.58.208.99... connected
* Connected to www.google.co.uk (216.58.208.99) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: none
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I've checked that ca-bundle.crt exists in that location, but to be honest this is far beyond my area of expertise. I've tried this as my usual user and as root.

- CentOS 6.8
- WHM 56.0
- curl 7.19.7-52.el6

Any ideas what I should try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue too...
There is a temporary solution.

`export NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1`

For details see https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10930 and https://gryzli.info/2016/05/28/centos-6-curl-ssl-illegal-instruction-error/

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. And thanks for those links too, useful to see the background to the issue.